# Use sklearn GridSearchCV on custom class whose fit method takes 3 arguments

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm working on a project that involves implementing some algorithms as python classes and testing their performance. I decided to write them up as sklearn estimators so that I could use [`GridSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) for validation.

However, one of my algorithms for [Inductive Matrix Completion](http://bigdata.ices.utexas.edu/software/inductive-matrix-completion/) takes more than just `X` and `y` as arguments. This becomes a problem for the [`GridSearchCV.fit`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L558) as there appears to be no way to pass more than just `X` and `y` to the fit method of the estimator. The source shows the following arguments for `GridSearchCV.fit`:

`def fit(self, X, y=None, groups=None, **fit_params):`

And of course the downstream methods expect only these two arguments. Obviously it would be no trivial task (or advisable) to modify my local copy of `GridSearchCV` to accommodate my needs.

For reference IMC basically states that $ R \approx XW^THY^T $. So my fit method takes the following form:

`def fit(self, R, X, Y):`

So trying the following fails as the Y value never gets passed to the `IMC.fit` method:

```
imc = IMC()
params = {...}
gs = GridSearchCV(imc, param_grid=params)
gs.fit(R, X, Y)
```

I've created a workaround for this by modifying the `IMC.fit` method like so (this also has to be inserted into the `score` method):

```
def fit(self, R, X, Y=None):
    if Y is None:
        split = np.where(np.all(X == 999, axis=0))[0][0]
        Y = X[:, split + 1:]
        X = X[:, :split]
    ...
```

This allows me to use [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) to stack X and Y horizontally and insert a column of all `999` between them. This array can then be passed to `GridSearchCV.fit` as follows:

```
data = np.hstack([X, np.ones((X.shape[0],1)) * 999, Y])
gs.fit(R, data)
```

This approach works, but feels pretty hacky. Therefore my question is this:

#### Is there a generally accepted way or best practice for passing more than 2 arguments to a fit method using `GridSearchCV`?

Comment: What is the problem in using **fit_params, which you mention above yourself? See: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.fit

Comment: @MarcusV. I believe I misunderstood your comment yesterday. I went back and tested using the `**fit_params` but ended up running into an issue with the scorer. Apparently the `fit_params` do not get cascaded down to the scoring method and since I am using the default `score` method in my class the additional matrices do not get passed in. See [sklearn.model_selection._validation._score](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a805efbe4bb06516670a9b8c690992bd7/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L495)

Answer (score 2):

So after getting some inspiration from a friend on this ([@Matthew Drury](https://stackexchange.com/users/2660392/matthew-drury?tab=accounts)) I constructed a much more elegant solution.

Again the problem is framed as such:

I have a matrix completion method that takes `X`, `Y`, and `R` as arguments and attempts to construct `W` and `H` that minimize `R - XWHY` for all observed indices in `R`. A basic implementation of a `fit` method would look like this:

```
def fit(X, Y, R):
    W, H = do_minimization(X, Y, R)
    return W, H
```

This doesn't fit well into the standard sklearn model where fit takes an `X` (the features that feed into a model) and `y` (the results) and looks like this:

```
def fit(X, y):
    W, H = do_minimization(X, y)
    return W, H
```

This isn't really an issue until you start using `GridSearchCV` or other cross validation methods as they expect the data to fit the latter format. So to marry these two concepts I needed a way of packaging two disparate matrices `X` and `Y` into a single structure without losing the separate nature of the two.

In the 5 minutes I had to dedicate to this originally I came up with the hacky solution. In a matrix `R` shape `n, m` where the rows correspond to the records in `X` and the columns correspond to the records in `Y`, there are `b` total entries. If we take the row and column indices for all of these entries and index `X` on the rows and `Y` on the columns we will end up with equal length matrices for `X` and `Y`. These can then be stacked horizontally, separated by a column of nonsense, and passed to the cross validation methods without issue (we just need a couple helper methods inside the original class to reconstruct the original `X` and `Y` from the stack before fitting.

The point of this question was to find the elegant solution, or preferably an existing solution. That doesn't seem to be the case so I will propose the following model for any future estimators/classifiers built inheriting from sklearn that require more than just a single feature matrix for the fit method.

### Create a DataHandler

When using `GridSearchCV` the `fit` method does a round of checks before firing off any calls to the estimators `fit` method. One of these determines if the passed `X` array is [indexable](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a805efbe4bb06516670a9b8c690992bd7/sklearn/utils/validation.py#L176).  This test basically checks if `X` implements `__getitem__` or `iloc` and is the same length as `y`. This length check requires `X` to have a `shape` attribute. At that point the split indices and fits can be computed as expected. So we need a wrapper that implements `__getitem__` and has a `shape` attribute.

```
class DataHandler(object):

    def __init(self, X, Y):
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.shape = self.X.shape

    def __getitem__(self, x):
        return self.X[x], self.Y[x]
```

Thats it! We can now modify the `fit` method to match the sklearn style, but in this case instead of `X` being an array, it will either be a tuple (the result returned by the `__getitem__` method) or an instance of our `DataHandler` class.

Now `GridSearchCV` will work as expected by just passing an instance of a `DataHandler` containing the `X` and `Y` arrays.

Comment: thanks for this information.  Given that this post is a couple of years old, is this still how you are handling this?  I'm a bit confused about what the `IMC.fit` signature looks like.  Is it `def fit(self, X, y)`, but `X` is either going to be a `tuple` or `DataHandler` instance?  Do you have a repo to illustrate this?  Sorry for the confusion.